# if statement always true regardless of conditional operator

Tags: bash, variables, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
#!/bin/bash
WATCHDIR="/path/to/my/dir"
OKTIME="7200"
RESULTFILE="/path/to/some/file.tmp"
DONOTHING="$(printf 'good' > $RESULTFILE)"
SENDMAIL="$(printf 'bad' > $RESULTFILE)"
ELAPSEDTIME="$(expr $(date +%s) - $(stat -c %Y $WATCHDIR))"

if [ "$ELAPSEDTIME" -ge "$OKTIME" ]; then
     $SENDMAIL
else
     $DONOTHING
fi
```

I've been staring at this for too long, I've done multiple revisions, output the variable to separate files to check they are working, and lots of research on conditional statements in Bash today. For some reason the script always executes `SENDMAIL` even when I've manually verified that `ELAPSEDTIME` is less than `OKTIME`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"$(printf 'good' > $RESULTFILE)"` executes the command in `$()` and replaces it with the output.

This means that you always execute:

```
printf 'good' > $RESULTFILE
printf 'bad' > $RESULTFILE
```

before you reach the if statement.

Please just avoid putting commands in variables. If you want a function, use a function:

```
#!/bin/bash
WATCHDIR="/mnt/remote/ian/test"
OKTIME="7200"
RESULTFILE="/mnt/remote/ian/result.tmp"
ELAPSEDTIME="$(expr $(date +%s) - $(stat -c %Y $WATCHDIR))"

donothing() { 
  printf 'good' > $RESULTFILE
}

sendmail() { 
  printf 'bad' > $RESULTFILE
}

if [ "$ELAPSEDTIME" -ge "$OKTIME" ]; then
     sendmail
else
     donothing
fi
```

Comment: Thank you, this will be my first script to utilize functions. I've been getting by reading random questions on here, checking man pages and doing google searches - thanks for the answer, I obviously need to keep studying.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your if statement. The problem is that you're executing both these lines:

```
DONOTHING="$(printf 'good' > $RESULTFILE)"
SENDMAIL="$(printf 'bad' > $RESULTFILE)"
```

First writing `good` to the file and then overwriting it with `bad`. I think you meant to not execute the content of those lines, until later in your script:

```
DONOTHING="printf 'good' > $RESULTFILE"
SENDMAIL="printf 'bad' > $RESULTFILE"
```

It seems very weird to me to use variables to store code like that though. It will work, but why don't you just do this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
WATCHDIR="/mnt/remote/ian/test"
OKTIME="7200"
RESULTFILE="/mnt/remote/ian/result.tmp"
ELAPSEDTIME="$(expr $(date +%s) - $(stat -c %Y $WATCHDIR))"

if [ "$ELAPSEDTIME" -ge "$OKTIME" ]; then
     printf 'bad' > "$RESULTFILE"
else
     printf 'good' > "$RESULTFILE"
fi
```

Comment: The `>` will be treated literally, so storing that code in variables will not work.